# How good is Mysql for school online Jurnal?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on an online school jurnal using php and mysql, Teachers must type marks and attandance in everyday. I think it needs huge resource. **How good is Mysql**? Should i use some other database and why? Answers will be appreciated.

Comment: More than perfectly good enough. And no, it needs way fewer resources than you imagine.

Comment: its as good as the db schema and php YOU write

Comment: thx. So it is not problem ?

Comment: if used correctly, its not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Risking an "opinion based" here, but still:

There are, basically, 3 free DBMS to consider (there are many more DBMS, but those are either non-free or not well known). Those three are: MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite. All of them have their advantages and disadvantages, google them for details.

For small websites that have to be compatible with 3rd party applications, it's fine to go with MySQL. For bigger projects where you deploy your own code, it'd stick to something more elaborate that has more features and is compatible to SQL standards - like PostgreSQL
For very small sites where performance doesn't matter, SQLite may be suitable if you don't want to waste time installing and configuring a DBMS.